# UIView slide from side on top of UITabBarController

Tags: uiview, uitabbarcontroller, uitabbar

I'm trying to achieve this behaviour [image] [image]

The view from the right should slide when dragging. I have the dragging behaviour in place, my only problem is that since the view that is dragged is a child of one of the tabbar's viewcontrollers it won't be on top of the UITabbar. 
How can I arrange my view hierarchy so that when I drag my view it will be on top of the UITabbar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add the view higher in the hierarchy. If you do not support rotation, easiest solution would be to add as a subview of the window. If you do support rotation, window subviews are a mess to deal with, so go with the second best - add the subview to the tab bar's superview (normally, a container view of the `UITabBarController`). Remember to bring your newly added subview to front in the superview.

Cool layout, BTW! Why is the status bar's background a different color from the content?

Comment: hmmm. good idea. that might work. I've already implemented it as a plan b where it's added to the current view controller that's in the tabbar and I'm making the tabbar disappear when there's scrolling (much like in pinterest app). I did try to add it as a subview of the window back when I thought we support rotation and you're right. it was a mess. but I recently found that we dropped that so it might be a good idea. I'm going to try it anyway. as for the status bar, I'm not sure why it has a different colour. maybe the design team forgot to change that :)

Comment: @alex Ah, are these mock ups? Cool. Status bar should be over the content and not with a background of itself. Let me know if you need anything else.

Comment: I'm not sure exactly what you mean. The design is a bit wrong here. this tabbar view controller is not pushed but it presented as modal. so the status bar's colour is not changing. or at least I'm not sure how to do it in this case. I use storyboard and the app must be compatible with ios 6 as well. thanks

Comment: @alex Is that a navigation controller or are you using just a navigation bar in there? If it's a controller, it should take care of the status bar by itself.

Comment: yes. I'm using a navigation controller. but as I was saying I'm also supporting ios 6. this behaviour happens only on ios 7 but I need to have some consistency between the two

Comment: @alex You should strive to have best look under iOS7, not to limit yourself to the lowest common denominator. iOS7 marketshare is now at 87%. It's a no brainer.

Comment: yep. meanwhile I've arrived at the same conclusion :) thanks for the tips @Leo Natan

Comment: I have another question if you could help me. How should I add shadow to the view that has the December label on it? If I have a background image with shadow, when I scroll the tableview you can see the solid border of the view. What I want to achieve is when I scroll I should only see the shadow , like it's natural. Thanks